# Various Error Codes within simple font color CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to change the font color of part of a client's site and I am getting the errors in the photo below. Can someone please point out the errors in the code? I will also post code below.

```
`<script type="text/css">
div.nn-review-inner-cont>h2, div.nn-samap-inner-cont>h2 {
   color: #000000;
}
div.nn-review-header h3, div.nn-samap-header h3 {
    color: #000000;
}
p.nn-review-body, p.nn-samap-body {
    color: #000000;
}
div.nn-review-inner-cont, div.nn-samap-inner-cont {
    color: #000000;
}
</script>`
```

[Photo of code and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5kME.png)

Comment: I don't see why you'd have `<script type="text/css">`. CSS goes inside `<style>` tags

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS text goes inside `<style>` tags; only JavaScript goes inside `<script>` tags.